# Some beginner error I don't understand in python

Tags: python, pydev

So here's the code, I copied it character for character from codecademy, and tried altering it, only to get the same error. I'm aware codecademy is utilising python 2, but the differences wouldn't be so large that basic "%s" wouldn't work!

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print ("%s + %s + %s") % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
```

and this is my error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Sunil\Desktop\Beginning Programming\Java\workspace\Helain\src\packag\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
 print ("%s + %s + %s") % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3, `print` is a function, so this code calls `print("%s + %s + %s")` and then applies `%` to the result of that call, which is None.

Try `print ("%s + %s + %s" % (now.year, now.month, now.day))`

Comment: Ahh, thank you for your brief yet easy to understand explanation! Thank you for answering this question and some of my future questions I'll inevitably get!

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting also.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print ("{}+{}+{}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day))
```